# When was the picture of Amy and her baby taken?

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel

In the Season 6 two-part opener of *Doctor Who*, Amy Pond stumbles upon a picture of herself smiling and holding a baby.  This was in an orphanage in 1969 America.  This presumably was taken later on in her personal timeline after she had the baby, but the sequence of events revealed in *A Good Man Goes To War* contradicts this picture.

The picture shows a happy Amy holding her newborn baby.  But we find she gave birth to Melody while captured by The Church and Silence, so she wouldn't have had this picture taken then.  Afterwards, she never had a chance to hold baby Melody, so where'd that picture come from?

Comment: Are we sure she was holding *her* baby? And, for that matter, since this is Doctor Who, are we sure it was the Amy we know, from this universe?

Comment: Perhaps The Church created another Flesh duplicate of Amy to raise Melody (at least for the first few years), and the picture was of the duplicate?

Comment: Or maybe it was Photoshopped?

Comment: I don't think this has been revealed (yet), but I'll check when I have the chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've hit on an oversight by Steven Moffatt and associates, unless baby Melody returns in a later season.  Your timeline is correct so unless it was staged while she was captured (she holds the baby then, before the reveal about the baby) there would be no other opportunity.